# Using same component for similar routes - refresh issues

Tags: reactjs

I have two routes (react-router v4):

```
<Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
<Route exact path='/tag/:tag' component={HomePage}/>
```

where the top route shows a list of places and the second route shows a list of places that contain a specific tag. I wanted to set things up like this to reuse the `HomePage` component.

However, if I'm viewing places with a tag and then click on a link `<Link to="/">Homepage</Link>` then it doesn't reload all places (Axios/Redux) because (I assume) the Homepage component is already in use.

Should I force a reload in some way, make a second component that's very similar to `HomePage` and duplicate code or is there an even better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lifecycle method componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){}.
Inside this method you will get the path inside this.props and after getting path you can write your logic to modify the component on the basis of route received.